# How to adjust or let Apple Watch register that you already stood for 1 minute?

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

Sometimes I walk downstairs, wash some fruits, eat it, and walk upstairs, and for sure it is more than 1 minute -- it is more like 3 to 5 minutes.  But Apple Watch still did not register me standing up for 1 minute out of the hour.  How do I make it happen, or set the 12 hours out of a day lower?

(Update: yesterday I stood for 5 minutes and it didn't register the standing up, and only after 10 minutes, then it registered).

For example, how does the watch find out whether I am washing fruit standing up or sitting down?  A coworker put boxes under the keyboard and the monitor and typed and used the mouse for a few hours standing up, and how does the watch know whether he was typing standing up or sitting down? (especially if it was the 2nd floor or 3rd floor, when the elevation of the watch is 18 feet or 27 feet, then how does the watch know whether the person is sitting down or standing up?).

There was also a day when I was quite active for a few hours during the day, worked out for 45 minutes, and also attended two physical activity classes, each for 1 hour.  So my day should be quite complete, but the watch register only 10 hours of standing up during the day, and therefore did not consider my daily goal completed.

So how do I make the watch register my standing up more accurately, or lower the daily goal, say, to 8 hours?

P.S. (1) I have also noticed that if I am watching exercise videos and following it standing on the bed, then for 35 minutes, the standing won't count as standing, maybe due to the elevation. (2) If somebody go for kite-surfing or water sports for 3, 4 hours, and not wear the Apple Watch just to be safe about water getting in, then it will be difficult to complete the "standing 1 minute for each of 12 hours", because if waking hours is 16, then minus the 4 hours of water sports, then he really has to register 1 minute for every single hour, or else, he can be exhausted from the sports that day, yet be recorded as "incomplete" for the daily activities.

Comment: I usually try and move my arm with my watch around. Try stretching or something.

Comment: I have the same issue.